# Worklight Server Adapter Errors

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We are using a pair of load-balanced Worklight 6.1.0.02.20150520-1015 servers in a production environment to support a mobile app with about 15 ~ 20k queries per day coming through to the Worklight servers adapters.

These adapters calls are not really doing any processing. For the most part they are simply passing http requests along to internal servers located in the same zone as the Worklight server. The internal servers typically respond to requests within 100ms or less.

We are seeing an average of 12 errors per thousand requests in the Worklight logs. They are roughly 2/3 UNEXPECTED_ERROR, 1/3 REQUEST_TIMEOUT, and 1/3 UNRESPONSIVE_HOST. As far as we can see, these requests never even reach the internal servers.

It is as if these requests are queuing up or failing on the Worklight servers somehow.

The adapters typically have these settings;

<loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="50" />

<procedure name=... requestTimeoutInSeconds="60" />

What should we be doing to reduce this error rate?

Does it indicate the servers need more memory or processing speed? Do we need to experiment with changing the settings? Or what?

Comment: Have you done Performance testing on non-production environment with the same infrastructure setup as production?

Comment: We have done and are planning additional performance testing but the non-production environment hardware is similar but not the same; a single server instead of a load-balanced pair having less memory than the production servers.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace from the logs?

Comment: @Michael, can you reply?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to open an IBM PMR (support ticket) by your business/dev unit, since this question is not suitable for Stack Overflow (more about infrastructure handling than programming). The support/dev team could then investigate and possibly provide a solution.